# How to make a request with Angular from Office Addin

Tags: javascript, angularjs, internet-explorer, office365, office-addins

I develop a Office AddIn, I want to make a request to my Web Services, but when the script start, I have an error with `angular.min.js` `(99,73)`, when the script make a request apparently.

So I have this problem because the html page is running by Internet Explorer and i don't know how to do for run my request.

For call my JS I have an HTML page, who is call by Word (when I run my addin with word), and i have

> 0x80070005 Access Denied.

The error comes from this function call : `u.open(e,h,!0);`

```
e = 'GET'
h = my API url
```

Please someone could help me.

Comment: what version of internet explorer is this? angular only support internet explorer 9+

Comment: Hi, thanks ! i don't know ... The page is run automaticly by Word and open a panel with internet explorer but it's not a real window.

Comment: i assume its using the version of internet explorer installed on your machine

Comment: I have IE 11.162. And i try to run my page from IE and i have the same problem ...

Comment: There are some security restrictions within the add-in container, such as which domains you can redirect to. I'm not too familiar with angular, but this "u.open" call.. does it make a request to another domain?

Comment: Yes it's here where the request is made

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i make the request to http server and office works with https.